# Check usertype at login (php)

Tags: php, html, admin

I made a website with registration/login system and I want to make an admin panel as well. I gave my account admin usertype (mysql) but I don't know how to check the usertype at login. This is my authenticate code that checks logins (echos have texts in Hungarian don't care about that):

```
session_start();
$DATABASE_HOST = 'sql305.epizy.com';
$DATABASE_USER = 'epiz_25331636';
$DATABASE_PASS = 'q1SI3G8B0s';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'epiz_25331636_accounts';
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    exit('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
    exit('Felhasználónév és jelszó is szükséges!');
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header('Location: home.php');
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Helytelen jelszó');
window.location='index.html';
</script>";

    }
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Helytelen felhasználónév');
window.location='index.html';
</script>";
  }

    $stmt->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: I trust that the credentials you've posted are not what are in use currently? Otherwise, you should look to change those as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you please describe your `account` DB table structure. where you are storing `userType` bit in DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `usertype` field for each user, which contains "admin" for administrators, you can do the following:

```php
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password, usertype FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $usertype);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            if($usertype == "admin"){
                header('Location: adminpanel.html')
            } else {
                header('Location: home.php');
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Helytelen jelszó');
            window.location='index.html';
            </script>";
        }
    }
```

And like already mentioned, please change the credentials as soon as possible, if they are in use.

Comment: Where should I declare the $usertype variable. I have the usertype column in my database but I don’t have a $usertype variable. Thanks for your answer btw.

Comment: There's no need to define ```$usertype```. The variable is assigned by ```$stmt->bind_result``` on the 7th line of my snippet.

Comment: Now it's kinda working, I don't get any errors but for the admin stuff I wrote `header('Location: adminpanel.html');`  but it still takes me to home.php (with the admin account) Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Put ```header('Location: home.php');``` into an else statement. (Adjusted it in the snippet in my answer)

Comment: Ok, Thanks guys, finally I did it. I'm really thankful for all your help.